# gpg failed in goreleaser

Tags: go, gnupg, gpg-signature, goreleaser

I am trying to use .goreleaser.yaml to publish binary files.

```
builds:
- env:
    - CGO_ENABLED=0
  flags:
    - -trimpath
  ldflags:
    - '-s -w -X main.version={{.Version}} -X main.commit={{.Commit}}'
  goos:
    - windows
    - linux
    - darwin
  goarch:
    - amd64
    - '386'
    - arm
    - arm64
  ignore:
    - goos: darwin
      goarch: '386'
  binary: '{{ .ProjectName }}_v{{ .Version }}'
archives:
- format: zip
  name_template: '{{ .ProjectName }}_{{ .Version }}_{{ .Os }}_{{ .Arch }}'
checksum:
  name_template: '{{ .ProjectName }}_{{ .Version }}_SHA256SUMS'
  algorithm: sha256
signs:
  - artifacts: checksum
    args:
      - "--batch"
      - "--local-user"
      - "${GPG_USER}"
      - "${GPG_FINGERPRINT}"
      - "--output"
      - "${signature}"
      - "--detach-sign"
      - "${artifact}"
release:
  # draft: true
changelog:
  skip: true
```

I used gpg key to push commits to the repo.

The problem is when i am trying to use signs in the goreleaser i get:

> ⨯ release failed after 138.65s error=sign: gpg failed

but when i am trying to run this command on my local laptop the command finishing successfully .

The command is:

```
gpg --batch ${env.GPG_FINGERPRINT} --output dist/terraform-provider-test_0.0.34_SHA256SUMS.sig --det
ach-sign dist/terraform-provider-test_0.0.34_SHA256SUM
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I would recommend running with `--debug` to catch more logs about what might be the issue...